# How Merge Database in Redis

Tags: redis

Here My Code

```
#!/bin/bash
db1_prot=6379         # Cổng DB1
db1_dump_num=1        # Cơ sở dữ liệu đích DB1
db2_prot=6379         # Cổng DB2
db2_dump_num=2        # Cơ sở dữ liệu nguồn DB2
`# get all field with value from key "Account" in DB2 and add to DB1
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p $db2_prot -n $db2_dump_num HGETALL "Account" | \
{
   while read -r field && read -r value
   do   
    redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p $db1_prot -n $db1_dump_num HSET "Account" "$field" "$value"
   done
 }
```

Detail Ex:

```
DB1=> Key: Account, Field: 1_local_123456, value: \x91\x95\x01\x01\xA8S1.74495\xCF\x00\x00\x08\x00\x80\x00\x00\x01\xCF\x00\x00\x01\x89\x82L\x8A\xBE
DB2=> Key: Account, Field: 2_local_123456, value: \x91\x95\x01\x01\xA8S1.74495\xCF\x00\x00\x08\x00\x80\x00\x00\x01\xCF\x00\x00\x01\x89\x82L\x8A\xBE
```

Error:

> After merge DB2 -> Db1: Value of field from Key Account ( DB2 ): only left: \x91\x95\x01\x01\xA8S1.74495\xCF

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.